Sci-Fi book about a marine captain called Jake who goes into stasis for 100 years
I have just found an audio book that is aprox 50 hours in length.
The books main character is a marine captain Jake.
Series starts with him going into stasis in an underground test facility and waking up 100+ years later.
He discovers that he is the lone survivor in the facility.
To help him to the surface is an artificial life "Alice".
After getting acclimatized he learns that aliens have bombed earth back to the pre industrial a age.
There are survivors in settlements, raiders and such.
He decides to help a group that has gotten captured by raiders.
He takes the survivors to his bunker.
The bunker has the technology to make people learn while they sleep so from the initial batch of survivors he gets 2 doctors, a comms specialist, 2 combat specialists...
The survivors all agree to "share" Jake and most of them get pregnant by him.
Later in the first "book" he discovers that there are 7 more facilities like the one they are in so they start going on missions to the other facilities to expand. they also help out some communities that are close to the original facility. They gift them a hospital, give them modern weapons and train them in use.
Supposedly this is something offered on audible but I have no book name or author name.

This is AL:ICE by Charles W. Lamb.

Captain Jacob Thomas USMC is a divorced combat veteran just trying to
get his life back on track. Returning to the Marine Corps after a
failed attempt at reconciliation with his estranged wife, Jake
volunteers for a DARPA experiment that catapults him into a future
where humanity has been stripped of 200 years of technological
advancements and more than half its population. With the help of a
faceless benefactor named AL:ICE (Artificial Life: Intelligent
Computing Environment), he escapes the confines of an abandoned lab
facility and starts a journey to put earth back on a path to recovery.

He wakes up and the AI gives him command of her facility.

‘And the second reason ‘ALICE continued ‘is I am bound by my core
directive. I can only take direction from the facilities commander. I
was never directed to expose myself to the outside world. In point of
fact my primary instructions in that area are to keep this underground
facility hidden and secret at all costs.’
‘Hell, since he died over 80 years ago, that’s going to be a problem’ Jake said.
‘That is not entirely correct’ ALICE responded ‘The person who was the facility commander died 81 years ago. With his
passing the next surviving member in his chain of command assumed that
responsibility.’
‘But you said everyone was killed?’ Jake queried.
‘Everyone from that command is dead but you. You are now the facilities commander’


as always!! damn man!!!! Thank you so much!!!!

@Cherubel - You're very welcome.
